Is it possible to use parameterized queries within a dataset to dynamically showcase values from various tables on a Superset dashboard
I aim to refresh a single dashboard with different environments data based on user input. Although the tablename remains constant, the schema varies across environments. To achieve this, I seek to implement a parameterized query:
SELECT *
FROM {{ schema }}.csp__generate_access_token_by_api_token
WHERE to_date(header_common_header_data_timestamp) >= TO_DATE(DATE_ADD(NOW(), -7))

Here, "schema" serves as the parameter that could take on values such as dev, stg, or prd. User should be able to select/provide schema and view data accordingly.
